# Socket.io - Variables Not Updating Outside socket.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I am working with Socket.io and MongoDB. When I first send my `socket.emit` to the server, the server takes in the parameter and returns with my desired output. When I reach the `socket.on` on my `client.js` the OrderID is shown to the console. Yet when I exit the `socket.on` method block, the `GenOrderID` variable becomes `undefined`.

My question is: why are variables that were created before the `socket.on`, no longer accessible outside it.

Here is the `client.js` I am working with:

```
// Create order array
var Order = [];

// Create GeneratedOrderID variable
var GenOrderID;

// Get School ID from cookie
var SchoolID = getCookie("SchID");

// Generate OrderID
socket.emit('GenerateOrderID', SchoolID);

socket.on('GenerateOrderID', function(GeneratedOrderID) {
    console.log("OrderID sent from server is: " + GeneratedOrderID); // This returns the desired number
    GenOrderID = GeneratedOrderID;
});

Order[0] = GenOrderID;
console.log("GenOrderID is: " + GenOrderID); // This returns undefined
console.log("Order[0] is: " + Order[0]); // This returns undefined
```

Here is the `server.js` I am working with:

```
socket.on('GenerateOrderID', function(PassSchoolID) {
    // Connect to database
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Orders', function(err, db) {
        // Handle errors
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Begin creation of OrderID");
        db.collection('Orders').find({SchoolID: PassSchoolID}).sort({amount: -1}).limit(1).forEach(function (result) {  
            var GeneratedOrderID = parseInt(result.OrderID);
            GeneratedOrderID++;
            console.log("The server says the OrderID is: " + GeneratedOrderID); // This returns the desired number

            // Return to client
            socket.emit('GenerateOrderID', GeneratedOrderID);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your variables are accessible outside, but your `console.log()` is firing before `socket.on()`, which is an asynchronous mechanism.

Comment: @dvlsg So the `console.log()`'s outside the `socket.on()` are firing afterwards?

Comment: The general flow of this will (most likely) be: client emit, client setup `.on()` callback, client `console.log()` fires, server receives `GenerateOrderID`, server emits `GenerateOrderID`, client receives `GenerateOrderID`, client sets `GenOrderID` -- but the `console.log()` is long done by that point. You could try reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), if you haven't yet. It's not quite what you're utilizing here (which would be more like an EventEmitter), but the general concept is the same.

Comment: @dvlsg Thank you for simplifying the flow! I just moved the `console.log()` to inside the `socket.on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing the `console.log()` inside the `socket.on` I was able to have it work properly.

```
// Create order array var 
Order = [];

// Create GeneratedOrderID variable
var GenOrderID;

// Get School ID from cookie
var SchoolID = getCookie("SchID");

// Generate OrderID
socket.emit('GenerateOrderID', SchoolID);

socket.on('GenerateOrderID', function(GeneratedOrderID) {
    console.log("OrderID sent from server is: " + GeneratedOrderID);
    GenOrderID = GeneratedOrderID;

    Order[0] = GenOrderID;
    console.log("GenOrderID is: " + GenOrderID);
    console.log("Order[0] is: " + Order[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value of `GenOrderID` inside a callback function, which is only executed once a `GenerateOrderId` event has occurred. The code inside of a callback function doesn't run until that function is called.

For example:

```
function run(f) {
    // call `f` after 1 second
    setTimeout(f, 1000);
};

var foo;

run(function() {
    foo = 'bar';
    console.log('in callback:', foo);
});

console.log('before callback:', foo);

// output:
// before callback: undefined
// in callback: 'bar'
```

At some point in the future, `foo` will equal `'bar'`, but you can only **know** this is the case after your callback has been called. And you can only **know** that your callback has been called from inside it.